# Filter a field with timestamp (datetime) using today's date in Django

Tags: django, filter

I have a Django model with a timestamp field. I want to filter and get the number of rows containing today's date.
The timestamp field contains the date, time, and time zone.

I tried this:

```
today_date = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d" )
Pending = tablename.objects.filter(timestamp=today_date,).count()
```

But I got zero (0).

Thank you.

Comment: Is your timestamp field a `Datetime` field?
If so, the following should work:
`tablename.objects.filter(timestamp__date=date.today()).count()`

Comment: Thank you. This worked!

Comment: Can you also tell me how to filter the timestamp field to get rows that do not contain today's date?

Comment: You can use `exclude` for this - `tablename.objects.exclude(timestamp__date=date.today())`.